# Maximum Intermediate Volatility

Tags: r, cycle

I have two vectors, a and b. See attached.

`a` is the signal and is a probability.
`b` is the absolute percentage change the next period.

```
Signalt <- seq(0, 1, 0.05)
```

I would like to find the maximum absolute return occuring within each intermediate 5%-tile (`Signalt`) of the a vector. So if it is

```
  0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.06 0.07
```

then it should calculate the maximum return between

```
     0.01 and 0.02, 
     0.01 and 0.03, 
     0.02 and 0.03.
```

Then move on to

```
     0.06 and 0.07 do it over etc.
```

Output would then be combined in a matrix or table when the entire sequence has run.

It should follow the index from vector a and b.

`i` is an index that is updated by one every time that `a` crosses into a new percentile. `t(i)` is the bucket associated with the `i`th cross.

`a` is the probability vector which has length tao. This vector should be analyzed in its 5% tiles, with the maximum intermediate absolute return being the output. The price change of next period is the vector `b`. This would be represented by P in the equation below. 
`l` and `m` are indexes.

> Every time Signal moves from one 5% tile to another, we compute the
>   largest absolute return that occurs between any two intermediate
>   buckets, until Signal moves to another 5% tile.    For example, suppose
>   that Signal moves into the 85th percentile and 4 volume buckets later
>   moves into the 90th percentile.    We would then calculate absolute
>   returns between buckets 1 and 2, 1 and 3, 1 and 4, 2 and 3, 2 and 4, 3
>   and 4. We are interested in the maximum absolute return. We would then
>   calculate the max return in the following percentile bucket, move on
>   to the next, which could be an 85th percentile and so on.  So we let i
>   be an index that is updated by 1 every time that Signal moves from one
>   percentile into another, and τ(i) the bucket associated with the ith
>   cross.

This is the equation I am using. The notation might vary slightly. 
[image: Equation]

Now my question is how to go about this. Perhaps someone has an intuitive solution to this. 
I hope my question is clear.

```
"a","b"
0,0.013013698630137
0,0.0013522650439487
0,0.00135409614082593
0,0.00203389830508471
0.27804813511593,0.00135317997293627
0.300237801284318,0
0.495965075167796,0.00405405405405412
0.523741892051237,0.000672947510094168
0.558753750296458,0.00202020202020203
0.665762829019002,0.000672043010752743
0.493106479913899,0.000671591672263272
0.344592579573497,0.000672043010752854
0.336263897823707,0.00201748486886366
0.35884763774257,0.00536912751677865
0.23662807979007,0.00133511348464632
0.212636893966841,0.00267379679144386
0.362212830513403,0.000666666666666593
0.319216408413927,0.00333555703802535
0.277670854167344,0
0.310143323100971,0
0.374104373036218,0.00267737617135211
0.190943075221511,0.00268456375838921
0.165770070508112,0.00200803212851386
0.240310208616952,0.00133600534402145
0.212418038918236,0.00200133422281523
0.204282022136019,0.00200534759358306
0.363725074298064,0.000667111407605114
0.451807761954326,0.000666666666666593
0.369296011692801,0.000666222518321047
0.37503495989363,0.0026666666666666
0.323386355686901,0.00132978723404265
0.189216171830472,0.00266311584553924
0.185252052821193,0.00199203187250996
0.174882909380997,0.000662690523525522
0.149291525540782,0.00132625994694946
0.196824215268048,0.00264900662251666
0.164611993131396,0.000660501981505912
0.125470998266484,0.00132187706543285
0.179999532586703,0.00264026402640272
0.368749638521621,0.000658327847267826
0.427799340926225,0
```

Comment: "I hope my question is clear" no it is not clear (at least for me). specially this part `t(i) <= m < l t(i) < l <= t(i + 1)` can you precise the values expected here , for i =1,2 for example ..

Comment: @agstudy I added the equation into the post. Hope it clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Your introduction talks about `a` and `b`, their relation isn't clear to me yet but the data refers to these. Next you talk about buckets, but I don't see whether you take `a` or `b` to decide these buckets. Next you compute something for pairs. Perhaps “return” is a technical term here, but I don't know the formula behind that. Then you have a formula involving `l` and `m`, but I don't see where these come from. And it has some `P` which I don't get either. Are these `P` the same as the `b` from your data, and you use the `a` to compute buckets?

Comment: @MvG I added some more description of the problem. I'm building this off a ph.d. thesis so it isn't that intricately detailed unfortunately.

Comment: YOur `a` values are not ordered. So if you process your input in the indicated order, the you will pass between percentiles in both directions. Do you mean to open a new bucket for every cross?

Comment: @MvG the a vector should not be rearranged, as there should be created a new bucket over whichever percentile each iteration belongs into.

Comment: @Morten So my split using cut is not correct in this case...

Comment: @agstudy No, unfortunately not. I used a similar approach too to begin with, but realized it grouped them into each tile. I added a more thorough description to mypost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## My interpretation of the question

I hope I understand your question correctly. Here is what I understood:

1. For each row you compute which 5% percentile it belongs to
2. Whenever that percentile changes, you start a new bucket
3. All rows from the same bucket result in a single resulting value
4. If there is only a single row in a bucket, the `b` value from that row is the resulting value
5. Otherwise, you compute all `abs(b[l]/b[m]-1)` where `m<l` and both belong to the same bucket

## Basic answer

### Code

This code here does what I describe above:

```
# read the data (shortened, full data in OP)
d <- read.table(textConnection("a,b
0,0.013013698630137
[…]
0.427799340926225,0
"), sep=",", header=TRUE)

# compute percentile number for each line    
d$percentile <- floor(d$a/0.05)*5 + 5

# start a new bucket whenever the percentile changes
d$bucket <- cumsum(c(1, diff(d$percentile) != 0))

# compute a single number for all rows of the same bucket
aggregate(b ~ percentile + bucket, d, function(b) {
  if(length(b) == 1) return(b); # special case of only a single row
  m <- outer(b, b, function(pm, pl) abs(pl/pm - 1)) # compare all pairs
  return(max(m[upper.tri(m)])) # only return pairs with m < l
})
```

### Output

The result will look like this:

```
   percentile bucket            b
1           5      1 0.8960891071
2          30      2 0.0013531800
3          35      3 0.0000000000
4          50      4 0.0040540541
5          55      5 0.0006729475
6          60      6 0.0020202020
7          70      7 0.0006720430
8          50      8 0.0006715917
9          35      9 2.0020174849
10         40     10 0.0053691275
11         25     11 1.0026737968
12         40     12 0.0006666667
13         35     13 0.0033355570
14         30     14 0.0000000000
15         35     15 0.0000000000
16         40     16 0.0026773762
17         20     17 0.2520080321
18         25     18 0.5010026738
19         40     19 0.0006671114
20         50     20 0.0006666667
21         40     21 3.0026666667
22         35     22 0.0013297872
23         20     23 0.7511597084
24         15     24 0.0013262599
25         20     25 0.7506605020
26         15     26 0.0013218771
27         20     27 0.0026402640
28         40     28 0.0006583278
29         45     29 0.0000000000
```

## Additional columns

### Code

If you also want to know the number of items in each group, then I suggest you use the [`plyr` library](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html):

```
library(plyr)

aggB <- function(b) {
  if(length(b) == 1) return(b)
  m <- outer(b, b, function(pm, pl) abs(pl/pm - 1))
  return(max(m[upper.tri(m)]))
}

ddply(d, .(bucket), summarise,
      percentile = percentile[1], n = length(b), maxr = aggB(b))
```

### Output

This will give you the following result:

```
   bucket percentile n         maxr
1       1          5 4 0.8960891071
2       2         30 1 0.0013531800
3       3         35 1 0.0000000000
4       4         50 1 0.0040540541
5       5         55 1 0.0006729475
6       6         60 1 0.0020202020
7       7         70 1 0.0006720430
8       8         50 1 0.0006715917
9       9         35 2 2.0020174849
10     10         40 1 0.0053691275
11     11         25 2 1.0026737968
12     12         40 1 0.0006666667
13     13         35 1 0.0033355570
14     14         30 1 0.0000000000
15     15         35 1 0.0000000000
16     16         40 1 0.0026773762
17     17         20 2 0.2520080321
18     18         25 3 0.5010026738
19     19         40 1 0.0006671114
20     20         50 1 0.0006666667
21     21         40 2 3.0026666667
22     22         35 1 0.0013297872
23     23         20 3 0.7511597084
24     24         15 1 0.0013262599
25     25         20 2 0.7506605020
26     26         15 1 0.0013218771
27     27         20 1 0.0026402640
28     28         40 1 0.0006583278
29     29         45 1 0.0000000000
```

Comment: Could I return which percentile the result comes from in a vector as well from this?

Comment: @Morten, I adjusted the commands to include that information into the output.

Comment: I am getting some returns of Inf and NaN in the `b`output. Would you know what causes this to happen?

Comment: `Inf` sounds like `pm == 0`, while `NaN` might be due to both being zero. I have some doubts about whether this whole computation is in any way sound, particularly since we compute values for single-row buckets so much differently from those of multi-row buckets. But questions regarding the interpretation or soundness of some method might be better placed at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), with a suitable reference to the thesis you're using for all of this.

Comment: thanks for your input. Much appreciated. First run seems to produce the numbers I need. As for the interpretation/soundness there are a few limits, but the thesis presents them fairly well. It is a measure of the maximum volatility that occurs within the given proability range of the Signal. This Signal is volatile as you can tell from the data, so it is a more in depth look at how the abs returns and this Signal allign.

Comment: +1 @MvG for this good answer (although the Op was ambiguous and he didn't show what he have done).

Comment: @MvG - Regarding your method of creating the percentiles. It creates it from 5 to 105 with 5 increments, a total of 21 steps. Is there a way to get if from 0 too 100, starting with 5?

Comment: @Morten: the range labeled *x* is in fact the interval [x-5,x). So points on the boundary get mapped to the next higher interval, but the interval is still labeled after the upper limit, even if that number isn't included. If you want labels 0 through 100, omit the `+5`. If you want border cases in the lower interval, use `ceiling` instead of `floor`. And if you want even more control, use `cut`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand but here an attempt. My idea is to group data by centiles than do calculation on each group using `by`

1. To group data I create a new variable split

   ```
   ##dat$split <- cut(dat$a,seq(0, 1, 0.05),include.lowest=T)

   dat$split <- c(0,cumsum(diff(dat$a) > 0.05))
   ```
2. Using by, I can performs my function en each group. I remove the singular cases of NULL prob values or one values.

   ```
   by(dat,dat$split,FUN =function(x){
     P <- x$b
     if( is.null(P)||length(P) ==1) return(0)
     nn <- length(P)
     ind <- expand.grid(1:nn,1:nn)     ## I generate indexes here
     ret <- abs(P[ind[,1]]/P[ind[,2]]-1)   ## perfom P_l/P_m-1  (vectorized)
     list(P=P,
          ret.max = max(ret),
           ret.ind = ind[which.max(ret),])
   })
   ```

Here the result list. For each interval I show ,

- P ( Prob values),
- The maximum return
- The indexes from which this maximum is computed.

For example:

```
dat$split: 0
$P
[1] 0.0130 0.0014 0.0014 0.0020

$ret.max
[1] 8.6236

$ret.ind
  Var1 Var2
5    1    2

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dat$split: 1
$P
[1] 0.0014 0.0000

$ret.max
[1] 1

$ret.ind
  Var1 Var2
2    2    1
```

Comment: @Morten This should work now. I just change how I compute the split vector.

Comment: Your `expand.grid` and subsequently your result does not appear to honor the *m* < *l* condition. Your comment swaps numerator and denominator, but in any case the index of the denominator should be smaller than that of the numerator. That's not the case in your first result. Your split seems wrong as well: it doesn't split at fixed percentages (0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, …) but instead if two adjacent percentages differ by more than 0.05 *and* that change was in the positive direction. At least I read the question differently in this respect.

Comment: @MvG You're right for the expand.grid and the comment. I 'll correct it. But for the split The OP was so ambiguous,  so I show just the idea ( diff + cumsum classic trick).Thank you again for reading my solution.